# Maven creates class file 50.0, should be 49.0

Tags: java, maven, java-6, java-5

This is my setup:

- JDK 1.5 and JDK 1.6 installed, JAVA_HOME points to JDK 1.6
- pom.xml uses maven-compiler-plugin with `<source>1.5</source>` and `<target>1.5</target>`
- `mvn --version` displays Java version: 1.6.0_06
- Maven 2.2.1

Is it correct that Maven 2.2.1 creates class files with file version 50.0 with this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand Maven correctly, it just means it runs on the 1.6 runtime. The settings in the pom should determine the generated classfile format.

Comment: Looks I made a small mistake and forgot a clean on the target directory, then deployed the old version to the repository.